# iOS UITableViewCell setSelected:animated: always has animated = NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to make my own selection animation. I've created a subclass of UITableViewCell. I do my selection animation in `-setSelected:animated:` method. It works as intended when you select or deselect cells by tapping them. Problem is that animation is also seen during scrolling, since `-setSelected:animated:` is called on each cell before it appears. This is how reusing cells mechanism works, I get it. What I don't get is that it always calls this method with animated = NO either on tap or on scroll. This seems like a logic mistake to me. I presumed it was supposed to select cells with animation when you tap them and without animation when reused cell appears. Is `animated` parameter even ever used anywhere except manual calls? Here's my code:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    BOOL alreadySelected = (self.isSelected) && (selected);
    BOOL alreadyDeselected = (!self.isSelected) && (!selected);

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if ((alreadySelected) || (alreadyDeselected)) return;

    NSLog(@"Animated selection: %@", animated ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    NSTimeInterval duration;

    if (animated) {

        duration = 0.25;

    } else {

        duration = 0.0;

    }

    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];

    if (selected) {

        //layer properties are changed here...


    } else {

        //layer properties are changed here... 

    }


    [CATransaction commit];


}
```

This always goes without the animation.
I can't think of any other such an easy way to handle custom selection. Implementing `-didSelectRow` methods in controller seems so much worse and it's not called during scrolling, so reused cells will appear in a wrong state. Any idea how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I've found a temporary solution:

```
#pragma mark - Table View Delegate 

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:YES animated:YES];   
    return indexPath; 
}


- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];

    return indexPath;      
}
```

It does work, but I don't like it. The fact that TableView's delegate has to know something about selection and it's not all contained in one place bugs me a lot. And `-setSelected` is called twice when taping a row - with and without animation.

Comment: If you return nil from these `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` the `setSelected` won't be called twice... at least :)

Answer (score 4):

This is how table views were designed to work. When you select it it highlights immediately, so no animation is needed. However, you will (you should, anyway) see the table view cell deselect with animation when you pop back to the table view. You can see that by using this code in the `-viewWillAppear:override:`

```
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated]
```

That will happen for you automatically if you are using a `UITableViewController` and have its `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property to `YES`.

If you want a different behavior, you need to code it yourself. If the code you posted here is working to your liking, keep it. You could also modify the cell subclass to always pass `YES` to the superclass in the `-setSelected:animated:` method override.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure that we are talking about the same thing. AFAIK what you've mentioned is actually `-setHighlighted:animated:` which is called twice - at touch down event without animation and on touch up inside event with animation. Yes, it works as intended, and I use it in my subclass too. But selection event happens not only on touch but every time cell appears on screen. If I pass animated = YES every time then selection animation will happen during scrolling. Method `-setSelected:animated: ` sees no difference between tapping and dequeuing reusable cell.

Comment: True, the selected and highlighted states of the cell are intertwined. The act of selecting a cell causes it to be highlighted. Then it can remain selected even after it's no longer highlighted. I believe calling -setSelected:animated: is just a way of passing the animated information to -setHighlighted:animated:.

Comment: Seems like it's the way it works. I would use `-setHighlighted:animated:` as a trigger for my selection animation, but when you scroll sometimes highlight happens even without selection - so it's unreliable. Anyway, my workaround seems to work just fine for now. I'll come back to this if I come across better solution. Thanks for sharing some knowledge.

Comment: No, it's not unreliable. It really isn't. Apple's code is pretty solid in this area. But there's a lot of misunderstanding about how table views (and collecting views) work. Cells are getting reused. That's most likely the reason you're seeing highlighted cells that you don't expect to be highlighted. Look into -prepareForReuse.

Comment: I'm not saying Apple's code is unreliable! It's more reliable than anything I do anyway :-) I'm saying that if you use it for something it was not made to be used for - it can be unreliable. In my case - if I try using highlighting method for selection. To see what I mean, just open a table view in Apple's own app (recent calls for example) and scroll it for a while. Sometimes cells become highlighted when you touch them even they are not selected.

Answer (score 0):

Although being late in the discussion, here's a simple tweak to add in your cell code:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    // Whatever you need to do here
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 100.milliseconds) { self.setSelected(false, animated: true) }
}
```

Using `touchesEnded` instead of `setSelected` does the trick, either on the iPad or the iPhone.

Comment: I looked at how `touchesEnded` is implemented using a disassembler for `UITableViewCell`. It simply calls a private method `setSelected` which calls `setSelected:animated:` with `animated:false`. That would also explain the mystery behind who actually calls `setSelected:animated:` in the first place. 

Your solution is probably the best and least intrusive, although I think it may be fragile if SDK internals change.

Answer (score 0):

I found a little workaround with prepareForReuse method which is called every time before the cell is reused:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

private var shouldAnimate = false

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    selectionStyle = .none
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    shouldAnimate = false
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if shouldAnimate {
        //your animation
    }
    else {
        shouldAnimate = true
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.